# How can I back up local git history created by visual studio team explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

I had a computer failure and have to reinstall windows and all my programs. I have a project which has quite a bit of git history which I stored locally and don't want to lose it.

Where does visual studio 2015 store git history, is there a file or folder which I can copy which will keep my git history after I reinstall visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a .git folder in the top folder of your workspace that contains the git configuration for the workspace and all the data objects.  So if you copy your workspace, it will bring the git history with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will verify this when I get access to my drive again

Comment: I was able to confirm this answer today, as a note the .git folder is hidden by default so you will need to have "show hidden files and folders" enabled to see it. Thanks again.